# What are the best practices to prevent code loss while regenerating application with JHipster

Tags: jhipster

What are the best practices to deal with code regeneration and custom code in some complex project using JHipster? How not to lose custom changes while regenerating the project? Our team usually consist of 5 to 10 developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an approach named as side-by-side (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo) that requires discipline from developers.

Also `--incremental-changelog` new feature of JHipster 7 can help to manage incremental changes to SQL database, even though it's currently poorly documented.

Another useful feature is to generate your project with `@GeneratedByJHipster` annotation in your Java classes by using `jhipster --with-generated-flag`

If a team of 5 to 10 devs works on same app, it will be hard anyway without JHipster but even harder with JHipster. I see several alternatives:

- Use a microservice architecture to help isolating from others changes.
- For a monolith, I would recommend using JHipster only for bootstrapping the app, generate few base entities and then forget about it, cut down the dependencies with JHipster and develop the project as a usual Spring Boot project.